# How do I write a function in R with 2 parameters with a return of a percent?

Tags: r, function, vector

I am not really experienced with writing functions in R and I'm trying to write a function with 2 parameters - the first is a vector and the second is a number. The function will return the percentage of the elements within the vector that is less than the same (i.e. the cumulative distribution below the value provided). For example, if the vector had 5 elements (1,2,3,4,5), with 2 being the number passed into the function, the function would return 0.2 (since 20% of the numbers were below 2). This is what I have so far:

```
testfunction <- function(myVector, x)
{
uniqueCounts(myVector > x)/x
}
```

Comment: Just use `sum(x < 2) / length(x)` ... you don't even need a function for this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - the "2" is supposed to be a threshold you can change, so you do need a function.

Comment: @Marius That depends on how this is being used in the larger R script.  If he only needs to call this function once or twice, it can just be inlined, and then no, you wouldn't need a function.

Comment: `function(vec,b) sum(vec<b)/length(vec)` seems like an adaptation of Tim's code to a function. SLG333, what is `uniqueCounts`? I've never heard of that function, it's not default in R as far as I can tell.

Comment: whether one is necessary or not, the OP is trying to learn how to write a function. Obviously a useful thing. OP, you have the correct syntax here, you just need an expression that does what you want. @TimBiegeleisen has provided one for you.

Comment: @r2evans that's the point of the question, i believe. `uniqueCounts` is a placeholder for an expression that does what the OP wants.

Comment: I am suppose to write a function that I can test the function with different vectors and numbers. The one above is just the example. I had read about uniqueCounts but wasn't sure how to construct this function to get the percent with the vector and number changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the correct syntax here

```
your_function <- function(arg1, arg2){
    do_something
}
```

Here you also need an expression that will evaluate as you've described. @TimBiegeleisen has provided one for you, `sum(a > b)` gives the number of occurrences of a value greater than b in the vector a. The proportion `sum(a > b)/ length(a)` will give you the proportion of values in a that are greater than b, and should range between `0` for vectors `a` that have no values greater than `b` and `1` for vectors with all values greater than `b`, and will give `NaN` if `a` is `NULL`, `NA`, if `a` is `NA`. If you'd like to enforce `a` and or `b` having certain properties, you can add error checking.

```
testfunction <- function(myVector, x){
    sum(myVector > x)/length(myVector)
}
tesfunction(1:10, 2)
# [1] 0.8
```

In R, the last expression evaluated is returned by the function, if there is no explicit `return`. If you want to enforce certain properties, you include a call to `stop()`, e.g.

```
testfunction <- function(myVector, x){
  if(length(x) != 1) stop("x must have length == 1")
  sum(myVector > x)/length(myVector)
}
testfunction(1:10, 2:3)
# Error in testfunction(1:10, 2:3) : x must have length == 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with the expression! Just ran the function with my vector and it worked!

Comment: You can thank @TimBiegeleisen for the expression. I just put it into an answer and wrapped it in an explanation :)